# how to get local file with Restangular.service when a base url is not localhost?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

I need to get a json file which is on my local machine, but my baseUrl in Restangular is not localhost...

So, here is the question:
Is it possible to get local file with Restangular.service when a base url is not localhost ?

And how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

See this post : [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

It is not a problem with Restangular but with Javascript.

If you need it for test purpose you can try to find a way to do it (see the post)

If you are doing this in production, it is a bad practice. You should not access local machine from front-end

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Restangular for this instance, I would just use a simple $http.get() operation.